# Perform change detection using LandTrendr in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, landsat, change-detection, landtrendr

I am having very basic skills in LandTrendr. I want to make a map showing year of detection and another magnitude of change, but I keep getting errors. I suspect the problem to be with the image collection I  have prepared to use.

Here is my area of interest
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F7GNvYpnuEWzvft1JtJgINuagUecvejG

Here is the code:

```
var coefficients = {
  itcps: ee.Image.constant([0.0003, 0.0088, 0.0061, 0.0412, 0.0254, 0.0172]).multiply(10000),
  slopes: ee.Image.constant([0.8474, 0.8483, 0.9047, 0.8462, 0.8937, 0.9071]),
};

// Define function to get and rename bands of interest from OLI.
function renameOLI(img) {
  return img.select(
        ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
          ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'pixel_qa']
    );
}

// Define function to get and rename bands of interest from ETM+.
function renameETM(img) {
  return img.select(
        ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
        ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'pixel_qa']
  );
}


// Define function to apply harmonization transformation.
function etm2oli(img) {
  return img.select(['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2'])
    .multiply(coefficients.slopes)
    .add(coefficients.itcps)
    .round()
    .toShort()
    .addBands(img.select('pixel_qa')
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start'])
  );
}

// Define function to mask out clouds and cloud shadows.
function fmask(img) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}


// Define function to prepare OLI images.
function prepOLI(img) {
  var orig = img;
  img = renameOLI(img);
  img = fmask(img);
    return ee.Image(img.copyProperties(orig, orig.propertyNames()));
}

// Define function to prepare ETM+ images.
function prepETM(img) {
  var orig = img;
  img = renameETM(img);
  img = fmask(img);
  img = etm2oli(img);
  return ee.Image(img.copyProperties(orig, orig.propertyNames()));
}



// Define AOI on the map.
Map.centerObject(aoi, 10);
Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'f8766d'}, 'AOI');
Map.setOptions('HYBRID');

// Get Landsat surface reflectance collections for OLI, ETM+ and TM sensors.
var oliCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');
var etmCol= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR');

// Define a collection filter.
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
  ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 365, 'day_of_year'),
  ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50),
  ee.Filter.lt('GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL', 10),
  ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY', 9),
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI', 9)
  )
);

// Filter collections and prepare them for merging.
oliCol = oliCol.filter(colFilter).map(prepOLI);
etmCol= etmCol.filter(colFilter).map(prepETM);


// Merge the collections.
var col = oliCol
  .merge(etmCol);



// Define start and end years.
var startYear = 2000;
var endYear = 2018;

// Define a reducer.
var myReducer = ee.Reducer.mean();



// Make a list of years to generate composites for.
var yearList = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);


// Map over the list of years to generate a composite for each year.
var yearCompList = yearList.map(function(year){
  var yearCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'));

   var yearComp = yearCol.reduce(myReducer);
  var imgList = yearCol.aggregate_array('constant');
  var systemStart = yearCol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.min(), ['system:time_start']).get('min');
  // Reduce (composite) the images for this year.
  var nBands = yearComp.bandNames().size();
 return yearComp.set({
    'year': year,
    'image_list': imgList,
    'n_bands': nBands,
    'system:time_start': systemStart
  });
});

//print("image",yearCompList)
// Convert the annual composite image list to an ImageCollection
var yearCompCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(yearCompList);

// Filter out years with no bands.
//(can happen if there were no images to composite)
yearCompCol = yearCompCol.filter(ee.Filter.gt('n_bands', 0));

print("image",yearCompCol);

// define function to calculate a spectral index to segment with LT
var Ndvi = function(img) {
    var index = img.normalizedDifference(['NIR_mean', 'Red_mean'])
                   .select([0], ['NDVI'])
                   .multiply(1000)
                   .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'));
    return img.addBands(index) ;

};

var distDir = -1; // define the sign of spectral delta for vegetation loss for the segmentation index - 
                 


// define the segmentation parameters:
// reference: Kennedy, R. E., Yang, Z., & Cohen, W. B. (2010). Detecting trends in forest disturbance and recovery using yearly Landsat time series: 1. LandTrendr—Temporal segmentation algorithms. Remote Sensing of Environment, 114(12), 2897-2910.
//            https://github.com/eMapR/LT-GEE
var run_params = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};


// apply the function to calculate the segmentation index and adjust the values by the distDir parameter - flip index so that a vegetation loss is associated with a postive delta in spectral value
var ltCollection = yearCompCol.map(Ndvi)                                             // map the function over every image in the collection - returns a 1-band annual image collection of the spectral index

ltCollection = ltCollection.map(function(img) {return img.select("NDVI").multiply(distDir)           // ...multiply the segmentation index by the distDir to ensure that vegetation loss is associated with a positive spectral delta
                           .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'))});

//----- RUN LANDTRENDR -----
run_params.timeSeries = ltCollection;               // add LT collection to the segmentation run parameter object
var lt = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(run_params); // run LandTrendr spectral temporal segmentation algorithm

// define disturbance mapping filter parameters 
var treeLoss1  = 175;      // delta filter for 1 year duration disturbance, <= will not be included as disturbance - units are in units of segIndex defined in the following function definition
var treeLoss20 = 200;      // delta filter for 20 year duration disturbance, <= will not be included as disturbance - units are in units of segIndex defined in the following function definition
var preVal     = 400;      // pre-disturbance value threshold - values below the provided threshold will exclude disturbance for those pixels - units are in units of segIndex defined in the following function definition
var mmu        = 15;       // minimum mapping unit for disturbance patches - units of pixels

// assemble the disturbance extraction parameters
var distParams = {
  tree_loss1: treeLoss1,
  tree_loss20: treeLoss20,  
  pre_val: preVal           
};


// ----- function to extract greatest disturbance based on spectral delta between vertices 
var extractDisturbance = function(lt, distDir, params, mmu) {
  // select only the vertices that represents a change
  var vertexMask = lt.arraySlice(0, 3, 4); // get the vertex - yes(1)/no(0) dimension
  var vertices = lt.arrayMask(vertexMask); // convert the 0's to masked
  
  // construct segment start and end point years and index values
  var left = vertices.arraySlice(1, 0, -1);    // slice out the vertices as the start of segments
  var right = vertices.arraySlice(1, 1, null); // slice out the vertices as the end of segments
  var startYear = left.arraySlice(0, 0, 1);    // get year dimension of LT data from the segment start vertices
  var startVal = left.arraySlice(0, 2, 3);     // get spectral index dimension of LT data from the segment start vertices
  var endYear = right.arraySlice(0, 0, 1);     // get year dimension of LT data from the segment end vertices 
  var endVal = right.arraySlice(0, 2, 3);      // get spectral index dimension of LT data from the segment end vertices
  
  var dur = endYear.subtract(startYear);       // subtract the segment start year from the segment end year to calculate the duration of segments 
  var mag = endVal.subtract(startVal);         // substract the segment start index value from the segment end index value to calculate the delta of segments 

  // concatenate segment start year, delta, duration, and starting spectral index value to an array 
  var distImg = ee.Image.cat([startYear.add(1), mag, dur, startVal.multiply(distDir)]).toArray(0); // make an image of segment attributes - multiply by the distDir parameter to re-orient the spectral index if it was flipped for segmentation - do it here so that the subtraction to calculate segment delta in the above line is consistent - add 1 to the detection year, because the vertex year is not the first year that change is detected, it is the following year
 
  // sort the segments in the disturbance attribute image delta by spectral index change delta  
  var distImgSorted = distImg.arraySort(mag.multiply(-1));                                  // flip the delta around so that the greatest delta segment is first in order

  // slice out the first (greatest) delta
  var tempDistImg = distImgSorted.arraySlice(1, 0, 1).unmask(ee.Image(ee.Array([[0],[0],[0],[0]])));                                      // get the first segment in the sorted array

  // make an image from the array of attributes for the greatest disturbance
  var finalDistImg = ee.Image.cat(tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,0,1).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['yod']]),     // slice out year of disturbance detection and re-arrange to an image band 
                                  tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,1,2).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['mag']]),     // slice out the disturbance magnitude and re-arrange to an image band 
                                  tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,2,3).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['dur']]),     // slice out the disturbance duration and re-arrange to an image band
                                  tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,3,4).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['preval']])); // slice out the pre-disturbance spectral value and re-arrange to an image band
  
  // filter out disturbances based on user settings
  var threshold = ee.Image(finalDistImg.select(['dur']))                        // get the disturbance band out to apply duration dynamic disturbance magnitude threshold 
                    .multiply((params.tree_loss20 - params.tree_loss1) / 19.0)  // ...
                    .add(params.tree_loss1)                                     //    ...interpolate the magnitude threshold over years between a 1-year mag thresh and a 20-year mag thresh
                    .lte(finalDistImg.select(['mag']))                          // ...is disturbance less then equal to the interpolated, duration dynamic disturbance magnitude threshold 
                    .and(finalDistImg.select(['mag']).gt(0))                    // and is greater than 0  
                    .and(finalDistImg.select(['preval']).gt(params.pre_val));   // and is greater than pre-disturbance spectral index value threshold
  
  // apply the filter mask
  finalDistImg = finalDistImg.mask(threshold).int16(); 
  
   // patchify the remaining disturbance pixels using a minimum mapping unit
  if(mmu > 1){
    var mmuPatches = finalDistImg.select(['yod'])           // patchify based on disturbances having the same year of detection
                            .connectedPixelCount(mmu, true) // count the number of pixel in a candidate patch
                            .gte(mmu);                      // are the the number of pixels per candidate patch greater than user-defined minimum mapping unit?
    finalDistImg = finalDistImg.updateMask(mmuPatches);     // mask the pixels/patches that are less than minimum mapping unit
  } 
  
  return finalDistImg; // return the filtered greatest disturbance attribute image
};

var viz = {
  min: 2001,
  max: 2017,
  palette: ['#9400D3', '#4B0082', '#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF7F00', '#FF0000']
};

// run the dist extract function
var distImg = extractDisturbance(lt.select('LandTrendr'), distDir, distParams);

Map.addLayer(distImg.select(['yod']).clip(aoi), viz, 'Year of Detection');    // add disturbance year of detection to map

// set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
style: {
position: 'bottom-left',
padding: '8px 15px'
}
});
 
// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
value: 'Year',
style: {
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: '18px',
margin: '0 0 4px 0',
padding: '0'
}
});
 
// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);
 
// create the legend image
var lon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude');
var gradient = lon.multiply((viz.max-viz.min)/100.0).add(viz.min);
var legendImage = gradient.visualize(viz);
 
// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(viz['max'])
],
});
 
legend.add(panel);
 
// create thumbnail from the image
var thumbnail = ui.Thumbnail({
image: legendImage,
params: {bbox:'0,0,10,100', dimensions:'10x200'},
style: {padding: '1px', position: 'bottom-center'}
});
 
// add the thumbnail to the legend
legend.add(thumbnail);
 
// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(viz['min'])
],
});
 
legend.add(panel);
 
Map.add(legend);
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? Also, can you please publicly share your `aoi` asset. Your script is successful using a different AOI: https://code.earthengine.google.com/59ff7de6808bfa2bd8cff3473d93908c

Comment: Additionally, I recommend using the LT-GEE API to make working with LandTrendr in Earth Engine easier. Here is the function to do change detection - see the full example included at the bottom of the function description: https://emapr.github.io/LT-GEE/api.html#getchangemap

Answer (score 1):

```
var aoi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-47.05253256069382, -10.953258609139985],
          [-47.05253256069382, -11.025045428557927],
          [-46.98352468715866, -11.025045428557927],
          [-46.98352468715866, -10.953258609139985]]], null, false);


var coefficients = {
  itcps: ee.Image.constant([0.0003, 0.0088, 0.0061, 0.0412, 0.0254, 0.0172]).multiply(10000),
  slopes: ee.Image.constant([0.8474, 0.8483, 0.9047, 0.8462, 0.8937, 0.9071]),
};


// Define start and end years.
var startYear = 2009;
var endYear = 2019;

var viz = {
  min: 2009,
  max: 2019,
  palette: ['#9400D3', '#4B0082', '#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FFFF00', '#FF7F00', '#FF0000']
};

// define disturbance mapping filter parameters 
var treeLoss1  = 175;      // delta filter for 1 year duration disturbance, <= will not be included as disturbance - units are in units of segIndex defined in the following function definition
var treeLoss20 = 80;//80;      // delta filter for 20 year duration disturbance, <= will not be included as disturbance - units are in units of segIndex defined in the following function definition
var preVal     = 400;      // pre-disturbance value threshold - values below the provided threshold will exclude disturbance for those pixels - units are in units of segIndex defined in the following function definition
var mmu        = 1;       // minimum mapping unit for disturbance patches - units of pixels

var vizParams = {
  bands: ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 256,
  //gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};


var MNN_1989 = ee.Image("users/maximoicmbio/MNN_19890609");
var MNN_1999 = ee.Image("users/maximoicmbio/MNN_19990605");
var MNN_2009 = ee.Image("users/maximoicmbio/MNN_20090702");
var MNN_2019 = ee.Image("users/maximoicmbio/MNN_20190612");
print(MNN_2019)
Map.addLayer(MNN_2019, vizParams, 'MNN_2019');


// Define function to get and rename bands of interest from OLI.
function renameOLI(img) {
  return img.select(
        ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
          ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'pixel_qa']
    );
}

// Define function to get and rename bands of interest from ETM+.
function renameETM(img) {
  return img.select(
        ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
        ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'pixel_qa']
  );
}

// Define function to get and rename bands of interest from TM.
function renameTM(img) {
  return img.select(
        ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'pixel_qa'],
        ['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2', 'pixel_qa']
  );
}

// Define function to apply harmonization transformation.
function etm2oli(img) {
  return img.select(['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2'])
    .multiply(coefficients.slopes)
    .add(coefficients.itcps)
    .round()
    .toShort()
    .addBands(img.select('pixel_qa')
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start'])
  );
}

function tm2oli(img) {
  return img.select(['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'NIR', 'SWIR1', 'SWIR2'])
    .multiply(coefficients.slopes)
    .add(coefficients.itcps)
    .round()
    .toShort()
    .addBands(img.select('pixel_qa')
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start'])
  );
}
// Define function to mask out clouds and cloud shadows.
/*function fmask(img) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}
*/
// landsat 5 and landsat 7
var cloudMaskL457 = function(img) {
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = img.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return img.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

// landsat 8
function maskL8sr(img) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}

// Define function to prepare OLI images.
function prepOLI(img) {
  var orig = img;
  img = renameOLI(img);
  img = maskL8sr(img);
    return ee.Image(img.copyProperties(orig, orig.propertyNames()));
}

// Define function to prepare ETM+ images.
function prepETM(img) {
  var orig = img;
  img = renameETM(img);
  img = cloudMaskL457(img);
  img = etm2oli(img);
  return ee.Image(img.copyProperties(orig, orig.propertyNames()));
}

function prepTM(img) {
  var orig = img;
  img = renameTM(img);
  img = cloudMaskL457(img);
  img = tm2oli(img);
  return ee.Image(img.copyProperties(orig, orig.propertyNames()));
}

// Define AOI on the map.
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12);
//Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'f8766d'}, 'AOI');
Map.setOptions('HYBRID');


// Get Landsat surface reflectance collections for OLI, ETM+ and TM sensors.
var oliCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');
var etmCol= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR');
var tmCol= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR');

// Define a collection filter.
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
  ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 365, 'day_of_year'),
  ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50),
  ee.Filter.lt('GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL', 10),
  ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY', 9),
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI', 9)
  )
);

// Filter collections and prepare them for merging.
oliCol = oliCol.filter(colFilter).map(prepOLI);
etmCol= etmCol.filter(colFilter).map(prepETM);
tmCol= tmCol.filter(colFilter).map(prepTM);

// Merge the collections.
var col = oliCol.merge(etmCol).merge(tmCol);


// Define a reducer.

var myReducer = ee.Reducer.mean();
//var myReducer = ee.Reducer.median();
//var myReducer = ee.Reducer.min();
//var myReducer = ee.Reducer.max();

// Make a list of years to generate composites for.
var yearList = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);


// Map over the list of years to generate a composite for each year.
var yearCompList = yearList.map(function(year){
  var yearCol = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'));

   var yearComp = yearCol.reduce(myReducer);
  var imgList = yearCol.aggregate_array('constant');
  var systemStart = yearCol.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.min(), ['system:time_start']).get('min');
  // Reduce (composite) the images for this year.
  var nBands = yearComp.bandNames().size();
 return yearComp.set({
    'year': year,
    'image_list': imgList,
    'n_bands': nBands,
    'system:time_start': systemStart
  });
});

//print("image",yearCompList)
// Convert the annual composite image list to an ImageCollection
var yearCompCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(yearCompList);

// Filter out years with no bands.
//(can happen if there were no images to composite)
yearCompCol = yearCompCol.filter(ee.Filter.gt('n_bands', 0));

print("image",yearCompCol);

// define function to calculate a spectral index to segment with LT
var Ndvi = function(img) {
    var index = img.normalizedDifference(['NIR_mean', 'Red_mean'])
                   .select([0], ['NDVI'])
                   .multiply(1000)
                   .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'));
    return img.addBands(index) ;

};


// NBR
/*var Ndvi = function(img) {

    var index = img.normalizedDifference(['NIR_mean', 'SWIR1_mean'])                
                   .select([0], ['NDVI'])//NBR
                   .multiply(1000)  
                   .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start')); 
    return img.addBands(index) ;
}
*/

var distDir = -1; // define the sign of spectral delta for vegetation loss for the segmentation index - 



// define the segmentation parameters:
// reference: Kennedy, R. E., Yang, Z., & Cohen, W. B. (2010). Detecting trends in forest disturbance and recovery using yearly Landsat time series: 1. LandTrendr—Temporal segmentation algorithms. Remote Sensing of Environment, 114(12), 2897-2910.
//            https://github.com/eMapR/LT-GEE
var run_params = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};


// apply the function to calculate the segmentation index and adjust the values by the distDir parameter - flip index so that a vegetation loss is associated with a postive delta in spectral value
var ltCollection = yearCompCol.map(Ndvi)                                             // map the function over every image in the collection - returns a 1-band annual image collection of the spectral index

ltCollection = ltCollection.map(function(img) {return img.select("NDVI").multiply(distDir)           // ...multiply the segmentation index by the distDir to ensure that vegetation loss is associated with a positive spectral delta
                           .set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'))});

//----- RUN LANDTRENDR -----
run_params.timeSeries = ltCollection;               // add LT collection to the segmentation run parameter object
var lt = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(run_params); // run LandTrendr spectral temporal segmentation algorithm

// assemble the disturbance extraction parameters
var distParams = {
  tree_loss1: treeLoss1,
  tree_loss20: treeLoss20,  
  pre_val: preVal           
};


// ----- function to extract greatest disturbance based on spectral delta between vertices 
var extractDisturbance = function(lt, distDir, params, mmu) {
  // select only the vertices that represents a change
  var vertexMask = lt.arraySlice(0, 3, 4); // get the vertex - yes(1)/no(0) dimension
  var vertices = lt.arrayMask(vertexMask); // convert the 0's to masked

  // construct segment start and end point years and index values
  var left = vertices.arraySlice(1, 0, -1);    // slice out the vertices as the start of segments
  var right = vertices.arraySlice(1, 1, null); // slice out the vertices as the end of segments
  var startYear = left.arraySlice(0, 0, 1);    // get year dimension of LT data from the segment start vertices
  var startVal = left.arraySlice(0, 2, 3);     // get spectral index dimension of LT data from the segment start vertices
  var endYear = right.arraySlice(0, 0, 1);     // get year dimension of LT data from the segment end vertices 
  var endVal = right.arraySlice(0, 2, 3);      // get spectral index dimension of LT data from the segment end vertices

  var dur = endYear.subtract(startYear);       // subtract the segment start year from the segment end year to calculate the duration of segments 
  var mag = endVal.subtract(startVal);         // substract the segment start index value from the segment end index value to calculate the delta of segments 

  // concatenate segment start year, delta, duration, and starting spectral index value to an array 
  var distImg = ee.Image.cat([startYear.add(1), mag, dur, startVal.multiply(distDir)]).toArray(0); // make an image of segment attributes - multiply by the distDir parameter to re-orient the spectral index if it was flipped for segmentation - do it here so that the subtraction to calculate segment delta in the above line is consistent - add 1 to the detection year, because the vertex year is not the first year that change is detected, it is the following year

  // sort the segments in the disturbance attribute image delta by spectral index change delta  
  var distImgSorted = distImg.arraySort(mag.multiply(-1));                                  // flip the delta around so that the greatest delta segment is first in order

  // slice out the first (greatest) delta
  var tempDistImg = distImgSorted.arraySlice(1, 0, 1).unmask(ee.Image(ee.Array([[0],[0],[0],[0]])));                                      // get the first segment in the sorted array

  // make an image from the array of attributes for the greatest disturbance
  var finalDistImg = ee.Image.cat(tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,0,1).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['yod']]),     // slice out year of disturbance detection and re-arrange to an image band 
                                  tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,1,2).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['mag']]),     // slice out the disturbance magnitude and re-arrange to an image band 
                                  tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,2,3).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['dur']]),     // slice out the disturbance duration and re-arrange to an image band
                                  tempDistImg.arraySlice(0,3,4).arrayProject([1]).arrayFlatten([['preval']])); // slice out the pre-disturbance spectral value and re-arrange to an image band

  // filter out disturbances based on user settings
  var threshold = ee.Image(finalDistImg.select(['dur']))                        // get the disturbance band out to apply duration dynamic disturbance magnitude threshold 
                    .multiply((params.tree_loss20 - params.tree_loss1) / 19.0)  // ...
                    .add(params.tree_loss1)                                     //    ...interpolate the magnitude threshold over years between a 1-year mag thresh and a 20-year mag thresh
                    .lte(finalDistImg.select(['mag']))                          // ...is disturbance less then equal to the interpolated, duration dynamic disturbance magnitude threshold 
                    .and(finalDistImg.select(['mag']).gt(0))                    // and is greater than 0  
                    .and(finalDistImg.select(['preval']).gt(params.pre_val));   // and is greater than pre-disturbance spectral index value threshold

  // apply the filter mask
  finalDistImg = finalDistImg.mask(threshold).int16(); 

   // patchify the remaining disturbance pixels using a minimum mapping unit
  if(mmu > 1){
    var mmuPatches = finalDistImg.select(['yod'])           // patchify based on disturbances having the same year of detection
                            .connectedPixelCount(mmu, true) // count the number of pixel in a candidate patch
                            .gte(mmu);                      // are the the number of pixels per candidate patch greater than user-defined minimum mapping unit?
    finalDistImg = finalDistImg.updateMask(mmuPatches);     // mask the pixels/patches that are less than minimum mapping unit
  } 

  return finalDistImg; // return the filtered greatest disturbance attribute image
};


// run the dist extract function

var exportImg = extractDisturbance(lt.select('LandTrendr'), distDir, distParams).select(['yod']).clip(aoi).unmask(0).short();
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: exportImg, 
  description: 'lt-gee_disturbance_map', 
  folder: 'lt-gee_disturbance_map', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'lt-gee_disturbance_map', 
  region: aoi, 
  scale: 30, 
  crs: 'EPSG:32723', 
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

var distImg = extractDisturbance(lt.select('LandTrendr'), distDir, distParams).select(['yod']).clip(aoi);

Map.addLayer(distImg, viz, 'Year_of_Detection');    // add disturbance year of detection to map

// set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
style: {
position: 'bottom-left',
padding: '8px 15px'
}
});

// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
value: 'Year',
style: {
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: '18px',
margin: '0 0 4px 0',
padding: '0'
}
});

// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);

// create the legend image
var lon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude');
var gradient = lon.multiply((viz.max-viz.min)/100.0).add(viz.min);
var legendImage = gradient.visualize(viz);

// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(viz['max'])
],
});

legend.add(panel);

// create thumbnail from the image
var thumbnail = ui.Thumbnail({
image: legendImage,
params: {bbox:'0,0,10,100', dimensions:'10x200'},
style: {padding: '1px', position: 'bottom-center'}
});

// add the thumbnail to the legend
legend.add(thumbnail);

// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(viz['min'])
],
});

legend.add(panel);

Map.add(legend);
```